# Matplotlib candlestick: how to show multiple windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot candlestick chart in multiple windows. In usual line chart, I can use `plt.figure()`, `plt.plot()` then `plt.show()`. But this does not work for candlestick. Can anybody help how to overcome this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc

num,op,hi,lo,cl= np.loadtxt('AUDUSDdaily3.csv',
                              unpack=True,
                              delimiter=',')                        

ax1=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
x=0
y=len(num)
ohlc=[]

while x<y:
    d1=num[x],op[x],hi[x],lo[x],cl[x]
    ohlc.append(d1)
    x+=1

plt.figure(1)
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc[0:50],width=0.4)    

plt.figure(2)
candlestick_ohlc(ax1,ohlc[150:200],width=0.4)    

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `candlestick_ohlc` is the axes to plot to. If you supply the same axes `ax1` to both candlestick functions they will appear in the same axes.

Therefore remove the `ax1` definition. Then

```
plt.figure(1)
candlestick_ohlc(plt.gca(),ohlc[0:50],width=0.4)    

plt.figure(2)
candlestick_ohlc(plt.gca(),ohlc[150:200],width=0.4)
```

where `gca()` gets you the current active axes works fine. Alternatively, define the axes manually.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax,ohlc[0:50],width=0.4)    

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
candlestick_ohlc(ax2,ohlc[150:200],width=0.4)
```